# How to change ldap password using zend

Tags: zend-framework, ldap

I am working with zend framework, PHP , Ldap on Ubuntu. I am authenticating users from ldap using zend library. Now I want to change user's ldap passwords using zend. Any Idea?

This is the method that I am using to get zend authentication adapter. It is working perfectly and users are authenticated using this adapter.

```
public function getAuthAdapter(array $params)
{
        $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();

        $options = $front->getParam('bootstrap')->getOption('ldap');
        $params['username'] = split( "@" , $params['username'] );           
        $username = 'cn=' . $params['username'][0] . ',' . $options['server1']['baseDn'];                       
        $adapter = new Zend_Auth_Adapter_Ldap( $options, $username, $params['password']);

        $adapter->setIdentity( $params['username'] );
        $adapter->setCredential( $params['password'] );

        return $adapter;
}
```

Now how to change ldap passwords? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Zend_Auth_Adapter_Ldap for authenticating logins and such with an active directory.

For admin purposes of ldap, use Zend_Ldap.

Read the Zend documentation on the Zend_Ldap API, specifically the following

> **Zend_Ldap save(string|Zend_Ldap_Dn $dn, array $entry)**
>
> Saves the entry identified by $dn with
>   its attributes $entry to the LDAP
>   tree. Throws a Zend_Ldap_Exception  if
>   the entry could not be saved. This
>   method decides by querying the LDAP
>   tree if the entry will be added or
>   updated.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ldap=new Zend_Ldap($options);
    $ldap->bind();      
    $entry=$ldap->getEntry($user->dn);
    $entry['userpassword'][0]=$newpassword;
    $ldap->save($user->dn, $entry);
```

This is how it worked form me! Note that I did not encript the password before sending but the server stored it with correct encription.